Getting :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED error after installing react-native-lottie-splash-screen pakage in react native
Want to create splash screen in react native using react-native-lottie-splash-screen package after installing packages run npm run android command but getting :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses error more details:
 Task :react-native-lottie-splash-screen:processDebugManifest
package="org.devio.rn.splashscreen" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Applications/Senior Aid/MobileApp/senioraid/node_modules/react-native-lottie-splash-screen/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported, and the value is ignored.
Recommendation: remove package="org.devio.rn.splashscreen" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Applications/Senior Aid/MobileApp/senioraid/node_modules/react-native-lottie-splash-screen/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
46 actionable tasks: 36 executed, 10 up-to-date

I have try to find duplicate packages but according to error need to change in node_modules does it is correct way to fix this issue.
